# str_count in R - retrieving total frequency of a string

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to find how many times a certain string of letters appears in a dataset using str_count in R. For instance:

```
data <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "orange")

str_count(data, pattern = "a")
```

The output then being:

```
[1] 1
[2] 3
[3] 1
[4] 1
```

Is there a way I can produce the total output of the string's occurrence, like:

```
[1] 6
```

The dataset I am dealing with is much bigger, and I don't want to trawl through the whole thing looking for 1 or 2 occurrences of the string.

Comment: Would this do the trick?

`sum(str_count(data, pattern = "a"))`

Comment: `sum(str_count(data, pattern = "a"))` ?  Or do you have something more complicated in mind here?

Comment: Thank you both, I am very much a baby at this stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the sum:

```
sum(str_count(data, pattern = "a"))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R`

```
sum(nchar(gsub('[^a]+', "", data)))
#[1] 6
```